# Add LabelDecoration to Project Explorer in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, jface

In our Eclipse RCP Application, we have done some UI revamp which involves replacement of default eclipse icons with our custom icons.

For the above we have added a Label Provider for Project Explorer via extension to replace new icons. Although, with this change the decoration colors have been removed.

For instance, the projects checked out from SVN Repository are no longer showing color decoration for repository name with yellow color (As selected in Preferences > Colors > Basic > Decoration color)

Similarly, color decoration is now missing for Java Resources such as Data Type and method return type.

Current Understanding of Common Navigator:
When Project Explore is created, the label provider is set to

> org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider

We did override this to our custom Label Provider which is defined as

> public class CustomLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements
> extends LabelProvider implements ILabelProvider, ICommonLabelProvider

It looks like NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider cannot be directly extended by CustomLabelProvider.

Looking for solutions to be able to add a Decorating Capability, as per my understanding the following implementation in Decorator Manager gets all applicable decorators and apply the decoration:

> String org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.decorateText(String text, Object element, IDecorationContext context)

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_decorators.htm

Comment: `NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider` extends the JFace `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider`, you probably need to do that as well. The `IDecorationContext` that provider needs usually comes from `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator()`. The source code of all that is readily available, you should study it.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. Extending DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider requires my LabelProvider to add a parametrized constructer to call the super class. When I add this LabelProvider to plugin.xml entry for navigatorContent, it is not able to instantiate this LabelDecorator.  I believe I will have to add a base LabelProvider in plugin.xml and also add another LabelDecorator.

Comment: You have to write a class extending DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider with a suitable constructor.